# Accessing more than 1 method of a class using threads

Tags: c++, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am working on the following code:

```
r = gcnew RTMotionDetector();

Thread^ detectionThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(r, &RTMotionDetector::start));
```

Following is `RTMotionDetector`

```
#pragma once
#include "MotionDetector.h"

ref class RTMotionDetector :
    public MotionDetector
{
public:
    RTMotionDetector(void);
    ~RTMotionDetector(void);
    void start();
    void pause();
    void stop();

private:
    VideoCapture *cam1;
};
```

Here, you can see the thread is TARGETED to the `start()` method of `RMotionDetector`. But, not only this method, I need all other methods belong to this class to work on my call inside the thread.

So, is there any way I can put the whole class into the thread and call all of its method when I need? This class MUST be in a thread because otherwise it completely stops the other work, since this class is very heavy. I am fairly new to windows programming.

Comment: That question really makes no sense. Control flows through function calls. "Putting a class inside a thread" may sound good in bluesky meeting, but it just isn't how programs work. Every thread has *one* entry point, and it's up to you to create a suitable control flow.

Comment: Yeah - once start() is executing, it can call the other member functions on 'this', no problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Fine, then, I need to access other methods of the class using the same class where the thread is created. How this to be done?

Comment: @MartinJames: All the methods of the class 'RTMotion' will be called by the class where the thread has been created. 'RTMotion' will never call to its own functions. So, how to do this? any idea? please help!

Comment: You don't mean "same class where the thread is created". You mean "same *object*". Just call the other member functions as usual.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you mean something like 'r->pause()' ?

Comment: Just `pause()` if you're already a member function... or `r.pause()` from the outside, I suppose.

Comment: The thread is written inside 'Recognizer' class. pause method is belong to 'RTMotionDetector ' class. so inside 'Recognizer' I am accessing 'RTMotionDetector 'object. Since it is intialized with gcnew, 
it is r->pause() right?   ->